# How do I initialize flate2::GzEncoder outside of a loop?

Tags: file, rust, io, initialization, gzip

This outputs the raw and GZip compressed length line by line as a way to estimate string complexity:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead, Read};
use flate2::{read, Compression};

fn main() {
    let mut f = File::open("/etc/passwd").unwrap();
    let mut f = BufReader::new(f);
    let mut _buf = vec![0u8; 100];
    for line in f.lines() {
        let l = line.unwrap();
        let p = l.as_bytes().len();
        let mut e = read::GzEncoder::new(l.as_bytes(), Compression::default());
        let q = e.read(&mut _buf).unwrap();
        println!("raw = {}, zip = {}", p, q);
    }
}
```

I suspect that calling `GzEncoder::new` in every iteration might be expensive and want to move it outside the loop. How do I do that using `flate2`?

Comment: Judging by the public API of `GzEncoder`, this kind of thing is not possible. Even if it were possible, I doubt it would be _correct_, as the encoder is stateful, so it would be wrong for subsequent compression to refer to the state of previous ones. (You'd get unrealistic counts.)

Comment: Also, note that your `e.read()` invocation ignores the fact that `read()` can return less data than requested. You should call `read()` in a loop until EOF and sum the sizes obtained, e.g. [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3072ce62b7611360e4140f03d65de4b).

Comment: @user4815162342, nice comments, thanks.